# Connection to an RDS/Postgres foreign table is not working from outside AWS

Tags: postgresql

Consider a *foreign data* server on another database on the same host:

As `postgres`:

```
CREATE SERVER keys
  FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
  OPTIONS (host '3.128.X.Y', port '12345', dbname 'keys');
>> CREATE SERVER
```

Here is the `foreign table`:

```
create foreign table pkey (
     uuid varchar not null,
     pkey varchar not null,
     provisioned boolean not null default false,
     created timestamp default current_timestamp not null,
     modified timestamp default current_timestamp not null
 ) server keys options (schema_name 'public', table_name 'pkey');
>> CREATE FOREIGN TABLE
```

And the `user mapping`:

```
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR clip
        SERVER pkey
        OPTIONS (user 'pubkey', password 'pubkey');
>> CREATE USER MAPPING
```

Permissions are in place:

```
grant all on pkey to clip;
>> GRANT
```

Now let's try to use the `foreign table`: as 'clip' user:

```
select count(1) from pkey;
>> ERROR:  could not connect to server "pkey"
>> DETAIL:  could not connect to server: Connection timed out
     Is the server running on host "3.128.X.Y" and accepting
     TCP/IP connections on port 12345?
```

Note: this connection *does* work when run from *another ec2 instance* but does not work from my laptop.

The `Security Group`s for the `RDS` instance include individually whitelisted entries for the ec2 instance

```
Security group
Type                            Rule
default (sg-058f283ad029bf244)  CIDR/IP - Inbound   73.63.Y.Z/32    # Laptop
default (sg-058f283ad029bf244)  CIDR/IP - Inbound   3.128.A.B/32    # EC2 instance
```

- The connection from my laptop to the RDS works to the `clip DB`
- The connection from my laptop to the RDS does *not* work to access the `pkey foreign table` defined in the `clip DB`
- The connection from the other `ec2` instance to RDS *does*  work for all -  including to access the `pkey foreign table` defined in the `clip DB`

Comment: With  `psql` can  you connect to `host = 3.128.x.x  port=zyz`? If not have you checked in `postgresql.conf` whether `listen_addresses`  and/or `port` has been changed for that server?

Comment: Connection timeouts are usually firewall issues.

Comment: Since they are on the same host, have you tried specifying localhost or 127.0.0.1 rather than the real IP address?

Comment: @jjanes I got more details on the problem and have rewritten the question.  The connection only fails when trying to use it remotely. A strange situation since I would have thought the "foreign data" connection would work same way either from either local or remote client. I am uncertain why  it matters about the type of client .